# Как передать текст из QLineEdit в функцию поиска по CSV файлам?

Tags: python, pyqt, csv, qt-designer, qlineedit

```
import sys
import os
import csv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from interface import Ui_Form

# Criate application
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

# Crate form and init UI
Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
ui = Ui_Form()
ui.setupUi(Form)
Form.show()

# Hook logic

# Как присвоить значение из ui.lineEdit.text() в переменную?:
number = ui.lineEdit.text()

def search_tt():
    with open(r'путь к файлу csv', encoding='Windows-1251') as csvf1, \
         open(r'путь к файлу csv', encoding='Windows-1251') as csvf2, \
         open(r'путь к файлу csv', encoding='Windows-1251') as csvf3:
        csvf1_reader = csv.reader(csvf1, delimiter=';')
        csvf2_reader = csv.reader(csvf2, delimiter=';')
        csvf3_reader = csv.reader(csvf3, delimiter=';')
        for line_1 in csvf1_reader:
            for column_1 in line_1:
                if number in column_1:
                    id_tt_some = list(line_1)
        for line_2 in csvf2_reader:
            for columns_2 in line_2:
                if number in columns_2:
                    id_tt_net = list(line_2)
        for line_3 in csvf3_reader:
            for columns_3 in line_3:
                if number in columns_3:
                    id_tt_arms = list(line_3)
    return id_tt_some, id_tt_net, id_tt_arms

print (search_tt())
print(type(search_tt()))
print(len(search_tt()))

two_csv_bases = search_tt()

# Преобразование кортежа в два списка для дальнейшего использования
csv_list_some = list(two_csv_bases[0])
csv_list_net = list(two_csv_bases[1])
csv_list_arms = list(two_csv_bases[2])

# Тестовые выводы для отладки
print('Данные_1:\n' + str(two_csv_bases[0]))
print('Данные_2:\n' + str(two_csv_bases[1]) +'\n')
print('Данные_3:\n' + str(two_csv_bases[2]) +'\n')

# Run main loop
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: 1) А что передавать-то? У вас `search_tt` ничего и не принимает 2) За многократные вызовы по рукам надо бить: `print (search_tt())`
`print(type(search_tt()))`
`print(len(search_tt()))`
` `two_csv_bases = search_tt()` :) Сделайте один раз вызов, сохраните в переменную результат и работайте с ним :)

Answer (score 1):

Я увидел вашу задачу так:

```
import sys
import csv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

def search_tt(number: str) -> (list, list, list):
    id_tt_some = []                                                       # +++
    id_tt_net  = []                                                       # +++
    id_tt_arms = []                                                       # +++ 

    with open(r'csvf1.csv', encoding='Windows-1251') as csvf1, \
            open(r'csvf2.csv', encoding='Windows-1251') as csvf2, \
            open(r'csvf3.csv', encoding='Windows-1251') as csvf3:
        csvf1_reader = csv.reader(csvf1, delimiter=';')
        csvf2_reader = csv.reader(csvf2, delimiter=';')
        csvf3_reader = csv.reader(csvf3, delimiter=';')

        for line_1 in csvf1_reader:
            if number in line_1:
                id_tt_some.append(line_1)                               # + append
        for line_2 in csvf2_reader:
            if number in line_2:
                id_tt_net.append(line_2)                                # + append

        for line_3 in csvf3_reader:
            if number in line_3:
                id_tt_arms.append(line_3)                               # + append

    return id_tt_some, id_tt_net, id_tt_arms

class Ui_Form(object):

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(850, 370)
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Form)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 70, 611, 241))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(670, 70, 131, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 42, 541, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "Form", None, -1))
        self.pushButton.setText(QtWidgets.QApplication.translate("Form", "PushButton", None, -1))


class MainWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('Введите что-нибудь для поиска...')
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self._on_search)

    def _on_search(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()

        csv_list_some, csv_list_net, csv_list_arms = search_tt(text)

        self.textEdit.append("Данные_1:")
        for i in [ ", ".join(i) for i in csv_list_some ]:
            self.textEdit.append(i)
        self.textEdit.append("---------------------------")
        self.textEdit.append("Данные_2:")
        for i in [ ", ".join(i) for i in csv_list_net ]:
            self.textEdit.append(i)
        self.textEdit.append("---------------------------")
        self.textEdit.append("Данные_3:")
        for i in [ ", ".join(i) for i in csv_list_arms ]:
            self.textEdit.append(i)
        self.textEdit.append("---------------------------\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере не хватало данных для точного повторения кода, поэтому интерфейс сделал руками, он простой, но наглядный.

При клике на кнопку будет вызван метод-обработчик `_on_search` в нем мы получим текст из редактора lineEdit и поместим в функцию `search_tt`.

Функция `search_tt` отработает код и вернет результат.

```
import sys
import csv
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

def search_tt(number: str) -> (list, list, list):
    with open(r'путь к файлу csv', encoding='Windows-1251') as csvf1, \
            open(r'путь к файлу csv', encoding='Windows-1251') as csvf2, \
            open(r'путь к файлу csv', encoding='Windows-1251') as csvf3:
        csvf1_reader = csv.reader(csvf1, delimiter=';')
        csvf2_reader = csv.reader(csvf2, delimiter=';')
        csvf3_reader = csv.reader(csvf3, delimiter=';')

        for line_1 in csvf1_reader:
            for column_1 in line_1:
                if number in column_1:
                    id_tt_some = list(line_1)
        for line_2 in csvf2_reader:
            for columns_2 in line_2:
                if number in columns_2:
                    id_tt_net = list(line_2)
        for line_3 in csvf3_reader:
            for columns_3 in line_3:
                if number in columns_3:
                    id_tt_arms = list(line_3)

    return id_tt_some, id_tt_net, id_tt_arms


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.line_edit_search = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_search.setPlaceholderText('Text...')

        self.button_search = QPushButton('Search')
        self.button_search.clicked.connect(self._on_search)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_search)
        layout.addWidget(self.button_search)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def _on_search(self):
        text = self.line_edit_search.text()
        two_csv_bases = search_tt(text)

        print(two_csv_bases)
        print(type(two_csv_bases))
        print(len(two_csv_bases))

        # Преобразование кортежа в два списка для дальнейшего использования
        csv_list_some = list(two_csv_bases[0])
        csv_list_net = list(two_csv_bases[1])
        csv_list_arms = list(two_csv_bases[2])

        # Тестовые выводы для отладки
        print('Данные_1:\n' + str(csv_list_some))
        print('Данные_2:\n' + str(csv_list_net) + '\n')
        print('Данные_3:\n' + str(csv_list_arms) + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**PS.**

Работа с `search_tt` ведется в главном потоке -- в нем же работает и GUI приложения, поэтому если `search_tt` долго выполняется, то будут фризы (окно приложения перестанет отвечать). Чтобы этого избежать нужно использовать потоки (например, `QThread`) в нем будет вызвана `search_tt` и через сигналы-слоты передано значение `two_csv_bases`, таким образом интерфейс останется отзывчивым.

[Пример работы с QThread](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/05014056bacab35a7aa24b587e26c7017aef2922/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/qt__qtablewidget_fill_from_thread__with_api.py#L16).